# Cosa significa "calepino" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Artemisia*, di Anna Banti, ho letto questa frase che descrive la pittrice Artemisia Gentileschi:

> Lei non ha mai saputo scrivere che la sua firma e non ha *calepini* che per le invenzioni delle sue Ester e Cleopatre e Betsabee: senza dire che una madre priva di marito, madre di famiglia non è.

Ho cercato il significato di "calepino" in alcuni dizionari, ma non riesco a capire del tutto bene cosa vuol dire che Artemisia "non ha calepini". Significa che non ha libri?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calepino è sinonimo di dizionario/vocabolario, a volte è inteso come un librone. In senso figurato si può anche riferire ad una persona istruita. Betsabea, Ester e Cleopatra (qui prese al plurale, dipinte più di una volta) sono i soggetti di vari dipinti della Gentileschi. Il che probabilmente significa che a parte il conoscere i racconti riguardanti quei personaggi di cui dipingeva non aveva altra istruzione.

Se poi intendi calepino come libro è anche possibile che "non abbia altri libri a parte quelli riguardanti storie su ecc. ecc." Si dice che la Gentileschi (da giovane almeno, visto che apparentemente ci sono lettere da anziana) non sapesse scrivere ma sapesse leggere un poco, quindi non la vedo un'interpretazione improbabile.

Comment: Per quanto spiega il romanzo, Artemisia Gentileschi dettava le sue lettere.

Comment: Appunto, anche da trascrizioni delle testimonianze del processo viene fuori che da giovane sapesse leggere un poco e che era noto che non sapesse scrivere. In alcuni libri d'arte si trova che imparò a leggere e scrivere da "adulta", prima della morte ci sono delle lettere che scrisse a Don Ruffo, ma magari pure quelle erano dettate. Non so se il romanzo le menzionerà, non lo ho letto, ma sono famose specialmente per una frase.